# Notifications does not fire

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I am trying to create same notifications every 5 minute from x a.m. to y p.m.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [ .alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in})


    let hours: [Int] = [13]
    for hour in hours {
        for minute in stride(from: 35, to: 40, by: 1){
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "Title"
            content.body = "Notification body"
            var dateComponents = DateComponents()
            dateComponents.hour = hour
            dateComponents.minute = minute
            print(dateComponents)
            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: ("\(hour)"+"\(minute)"+"timerDone"), content: content, trigger: trigger)
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
            center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
                for request in requests {
                    print(request.trigger)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

It does not show notifications at planned time but

```
center.getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: { requests in
                for request in requests {
                    print(request.trigger)
                }
            })
```

print in debug that there are pending notifications. 
So, notifications are added to center and waiting for time, but don't fire.

Any ideas?

What that debug shows:

> hour: 13 minute: 35 isLeapMonth: false 
>   hour: 13 minute: 36 isLeapMonth: false 
>   hour: 13 minute: 37 isLeapMonth: false 
>   hour: 13 minute: 38 isLeapMonth: false 
>   hour: 13 minute: 39 isLeapMonth: false 
>   Optional(
>       Hour: 13
>       Minute: 35, repeats: YES>)
>   Optional(
>       Hour: 13
>       Minute: 36, repeats: YES>)
>   Optional(
>       Hour: 13
>       Minute: 37, repeats: YES>)
>   Optional(
>       Hour: 13
>       Minute: 38, repeats: YES>)
>   Optional(
>       Hour: 13
>       Minute: 39, repeats: YES>)

Comment: In which state is your device? Foreground, background or suspended?

Comment: @AlexWoe89 background

Comment: Do you want to schedule the local notification for every 5 minutes? If so, you can use a time interval instead. It's just works

Comment: @Mannopson not exectly, I need to schedule the local notification every day since 8 a.m to 8 p.m.(for example) every 5 minutes. By using time interval I cant stop at the specific time and start at the next day from hour I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your information that the app runs in `background state` it could be possible, that your app will be `suspended` after some time from the operating system.

**Background**

> The app is in the background and executing code. Most apps enter this
>   state briefly on their way to being suspended. However, an app that
>   requests extra execution time may remain in this state for a period of
>   time. In addition, an app being launched directly into the background
>   enters this state instead of the inactive state. For information about
>   how to execute code while in the background, see Background Execution.

**Suspended**

> The app is in the background but is not executing code. The system
>   moves apps to this state automatically and does not notify them before
>   doing so. While suspended, an app remains in memory but does not
>   execute any code. When a low-memory condition occurs, the system may
>   purge suspended apps without notice to make more space for the
>   foreground app.

I need to say also, that the operating system `suspends` your app also, even if you run some code. There are some exceptions, if you use `locations (geofencing)` or `voip` features

Please have also a look at following documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html

Comment: Well, I run the app. And when it runs I press Home button to see if notification will appear. 
When I don't use loop and just make 1 notification for specific time it fires. 
But when I want to do it in the for loop it does not fire